# error: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. - using laravel livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to do an image upload using Laravel livewire, but when I click on the button "upload" to test the functionality this error appears

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD'

The programs:

ROUTE

```
Route::get('/upload', UploadFoto::class)->name('upload.foto.user');
```

CONTROLLER (using dd for the tests)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\User;

use Livewire\Component;

class UploadFoto extends Component
{
    public $foto;
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user.upload-foto');
    }

    public function storageFoto()
    {
        dd('aqui');
    }
}
```

VIEW
@extends('layouts.app')

```
@section('content')


<div>
    {{-- To attain knowledge, add things every day; To attain wisdom, subtract things every day. --}}

    <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto" wire:submit.prevent="storageFoto">
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Change your route definition to POST, also for form action use the named parameter like `<form action="{{route('upload.foto.user')}}" method="post">`. You might be sending the request to another place!

Comment: I changed the "<form action="{{route('upload.foto.user')}}" method="post">" and the route but didn't work for me. The same error appear. What else could I change?

Answer (score 1):

You set get method on this route - but upload use post method. Change it:

```
Route::post('/upload', UploadFoto::class)->name('upload.foto.user');
```

Comment: Maybe because you have dd() function in action?)

Comment: So what can I change?

Answer (score 1):

please check this, you added `submit` in wrong place of form

```html
<div>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="storageFoto" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto">
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and you should check this lines into `app` file

```
@livewireStyles 
@livewireScripts
```

Answer (score 0):

change route method to Post

`Route::post('/upload', UploadFoto::class)->name('upload.foto.user');`